# Django: How to query for child, granchildren, etc. records in a non-horrible way

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to return a list/filter of users in my Employees table that have a nested relationship to the user. For example, I have employees tied to their manager, and I want to be able to query for all the employees under that manager (this includes any employees under any other managers that are under the main manager). So, if user `Bob` has 2 direct reports, `Sally` and `Brian`. And `Brian` has 2 direct reports, and `Sally` has 3 direct reports. I want Bob to be able to see all 7 employees. Right now, the only way I could get it to work was through a horrible sequence, as displayed below..I'm hoping their is an easier/more efficient way.

```
    manager = Employees.objects.filter(manager_id=request.user.id).values('manager')
    employee_ids = list(Employees.objects.filter(manager=manager.first()['manager']).values_list('employee', flat=True))
    employees = [User.objects.get(id=i).username for i in employee_ids]
    grandchildren = []
    for i in employees:
        user_id = User.objects.get(username=i).id
        child = list(Employees.objects.filter(manager=user_id).values_list('employee', flat=True))
        grandchildren.append(child)
    children = list(chain.from_iterable(grandchildren))
    for i in children:
        user_id = User.objects.get(id=i).id
        child = list(Employees.objects.filter(manager=user_id).values_list('employee', flat=True))
        grandchildren.append(child)
    grandchildren = list(chain.from_iterable(grandchildren))
    for i in grandchildren:
        employees.append(User.objects.get(id=i).username)
    employees = list(set(employees))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code looks really horrible. First of all, I mean too many DB queries (most of them are very non-optimized or not even needed).

According to your description, I suggest to try something like this:

```
manager_id = request.user.id
children_ids = list(
    Employees.objects.filter(manager_id=manager_id).values_list('employee', flat=True)
)
grandchildren_ids = list(
    Employees.objects.filter(manager_id__in=children_ids).values_list('employee', flat=True)
)
# If you want to go deeper, do this in a loop and stop once an empty list of IDs is fetched 
# (which means that there are no descendants anymore)

# Combine all IDs and finally fetch the actual users 
# (do it only once, and fetch all the users in a single query, not one by one)
employees_ids = children_ids + grandchildren_ids
employees = User.objects.filter(id__in=employees_ids)
```

P.S.: is this a joke `user_id = User.objects.get(id=i).id`? :)